# Android Renderscript, remove white/whiteish background from Bitmap

Tags: android, image, image-processing, bitmap, renderscript

I'm working on a picture based app and I'm blocked on an issue with Renderscript.

My purpose is pretty simple in theory, I want to remove the white background from the images loaded by the user, to show them on another image i've set as background. More specifically what I want to to is to simulate the effect of printing a user uploaded graphic on paper canvas (also a picture) with a realistic effect.

I cannot assume the user is able to upload nice PNGs with alpha channels, and one of the requirement is to operate with JPGs.

I've been trying to solve this with RenderScripts, with something like this which sets alpha 0 to anything with R,G,and B all equals or greater than 240:

```
#pragma version(1)
#pragma rs java_package_name(mypackagename)
rs_allocation gIn;
rs_allocation gOut;
rs_script gScript;

const static float th = 239.f/256.f;


void root(const uchar4 v_in, uchar4 v_out, const void* usrData, uint32_t x,uint32_t y){
float4 f4 = rsUnpackColor8888(*v_in);


if(f4.r > th  && f4.g > th && f4.b > th)
{
    f4.a = 0;
}


   *v_out =  rsPackColorTo8888(f4);

}

void filter() {
    rsForEach(gScript, gIn, gOut);
}
```

but the results are not satisfactory for mainly two reasons:

- if a photo has a whiteish gradient not on the background the script causes an ugly noise effect
- images with shadows close to the edges get a noise effects close to the edges

I understand that passing from alpha 0 to alpha 1 is too extreme and I've tried different solution involving linear increasing the alpha when the sum of the R,G,B components decrease but I still have noisy pixels and blocks around.

With plain white, or regular background (e.g. a snapshot of the Google home page) it works perfectly but with photos it's very far from anything acceptable.

**I think that if I'd be able to process one "line" of pixels or one "block" of pixels instead that a single one it could be easier to detect flat backgrounds and to avoid hitting gradients but I don't know enough about renderscripts to do that.**

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

PS

I can't use PorterDuff and multiply because the background and the foreground have different dimensions and moreover since I need to be able to drag the uploaded image around the background canvas once the effect is applied. If I multiply the image with a region of the background moving the result image around would cause a section of the background to move around as well.

Answer (score 2):

If I get it right, you wants to determine whether the current pixel can is a white background based on a line/block of neighboring pixels.

You can try the use [rsGetElementAt](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/renderscript/reference/rs_allocation_data.html#android_rs:rsGetElementAt). For example, to process a line in your original code:

```
#pragma version(1)
#pragma rs java_package_name(mypackagename)
rs_allocation gIn;
rs_allocation gOut;
rs_script gScript;

const static float th = 239.f/256.f;

void root(const uchar4 v_in, uchar4 v_out, const void* usrData, uint32_t x,uint32_t y){
    float4 f4 = rsUnpackColor8888(*v_in);
    uint32_t width = rsAllocationGetDimX(gIn);
    // E.g: Processing a line from x to x+5.
    bool isBackground = true;
    for (uint32_t i=0; i<=5 && x+i<width; i++) {
        uchar4 nPixel_u4 = rsGetElementAt_uchar4(gIn, x+i, y);
        float4 nPixel_f4 = rsUnpackColor8888(nPixel_u4);

        if(nPixel_f4.r <= th  || nPixel_f4.g <= th || nPixel_f4.b <= th) {
            isBackground = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (isBackground) {
        f4.a = 0.0f;
        *v_out =  rsPackColorTo8888(f4);
    }
}

void filter() {
    rsForEach(gScript, gIn, gOut);
}
```

This is just a naive example of how you can use rsGetElementAt to get the data from a given position in a global Allocation. There is a corresponding [rsSetElementAt](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/renderscript/reference/rs_allocation_data.html#android_rs:rsSetElementAt) for saving the data to a global Allocation. I am hoping it helps your project.

Comment: Thank you @Miao, it looks promising. I'm giving it a try and I'll accept your answer. I've upvoted it for the moment :)

Comment: You also might consider moving away from calling this via an invokable (i.e. filter()), and instead use the reflected Java forEach_root() function that we provide. You could also change the function to be pass-by-value, since you don't use the pointers and/or usrData at all.